# Splitting a pandas data frame's column containing json data into multiple columns

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I loaded and normalized a json data as:

```
json_string = json.loads(data)
df_norm = json_normalize(json_string, errors='ignore')
```

Say it has now 2 columns:

```
Group       Members

A           [{'id':'1', 'metrics': '34', 'profile': 'abc'},{'id':'3', 
              'metrics': '32', 'profile': 'dc'}]
B           [{'id':'2', 'metrics': '4', 'profile': 'bac'}]
```

I am looking for a method to split the 'Members' column and merging it back to the original data frame under the same 'Group', like:

```
Group   Members                                                                                          id     metrics     profile
A       {'id':'1', 'metrics': '34', 'profile': 'abc'},{'id':'3', 'metrics': '32', 'profile': 'dc'}]      1      34          abc
A       {'id':'1', 'metrics': '34', 'profile': 'abc'},{'id':'3', 'metrics': '32', 'profile': 'dc'}]      3      32          dc
B       [{'id':'2', 'metrics': '4', 'profile': 'bac'}]                                                   4      4           bac
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add sample json to question?

Comment: Yes please share `data`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import ast

#if necessary convert column to list of dicts
df['Members'] = df['Members'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
#create DataFrames in list comprehension
df1 = pd.concat({k:pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in df['Members'].items()})
#join to original
df = df.join(df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Group                                            Members id metrics profile
0     A  [{'id': '1', 'metrics': '34', 'profile': 'abc'...  1      34     abc
1     A  [{'id': '1', 'metrics': '34', 'profile': 'abc'...  3      32      dc
2     B    [{'id': '2', 'metrics': '4', 'profile': 'bac'}]  2       4     bac
```

Comment: Any suggestion how to avoid the below error "ValueError: malformed node or string: {'pkt_in': '2502', 'lport': '32872', "

Comment: I'm also getting the same error